# Which god do I serve?

Tags: nethack

So... I forgot which god I serve. I pressed Enter too quickly on the introduction dialog box.

How can I find out which god I'm serving? Is there a command or menu option?

I know I can pray, but that restarts my timer. The only thing I can think of is to sacrifice on an altar and hope there's a conversion message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a command that tells you your patron deity.  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to view your [base attributes](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Base_attributes); the pantheon for your role will be listed at the bottom, with your current deity marked with `(c)`.

Answer (score 4):

The Nethack Wiki has [a table](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/God) of what god you serve, based on class and alignment. The status lines at the bottom show both your class and your alignment. If you're a Priest, your god is chosen randomly among the other gods that share your alignment. That table is embedded as an image below

[image: God table]

Comment: For Priests: The game selects another class at random and uses that class's pantheon.  The deities in the pantheon retain their original alignments.  For instance, a lawful priest will serve one of the deities in the lawful column, and so on.

Comment: @Kevin I added that information to my answer

Answer (score 3):

Alignment is important, but the name of your god doesn't really matter.  It's great color and all, but meaningless.  See the other two answers for lovely tables of trivia.

You can see your current alignment in your status bar.

You can see the alignment of any altar.

A priest will match the alignment of the altar in his room.  Unless of course you change the alignment of the altar, which will quickly lead to a drop in the altar room's population...

The name of the god associated with a co-aligned Altar/Priest is the name of your god.

**Important**: If you have not yet finished your Class Quest, changing your alignment can be *very* detrimental to your game...

Comment: Technically, the name of your deity is important if you're planning on exploiting the astral call bug, but by that point in the game, you really ought to have it memorized.

Comment: @Kevin: I agree.  Avoiding knowledge of your god's name at that stage of the game would require what could most generously be called a *special talent*, or perhaps a devotion to the "atheist" achievement.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't realized that there will only ever be one god for each alignment per game.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your god depends on class and alignment (Lawful, Neutral, or Chaotic.)

- **Archeologist**: Quetzalcoatl,   Camaxtli,   Huhetotl
- **Barbarian**:    Mitra,  Crom,   Set
- **Caveman**:  Anu,    Ishtar, Anshar
- **Healer**:   Athena, Hermes, Poseidon
- **Knight**:   Lugh,   Brigit, Manannan Mac Lir
- **Monk**: Shan Lai Ching, Chih Sung-tzu,  Huan Ti
- **Ranger**:   Mercury,    Venus,  Mars
- **Rogue**:    Issek,  Mog,    Kos
- **Samurai**:  Amaterasu Omikami,  Raijin, Susanowo
- **Tourist**:  Blind Io,   The Lady,   Offler
- **Valkyrie**: Tyr,    Odin,   Loki
- **Wizard**:   Ptah,   Thoth,  Anhur

Priests are assigned one of the above pantheons at random, so if you find an altar, you can look up the name to verify the pantheon, then determine your god based on alignment.

(Source: [Nethack Wiki](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/God).)